# Creating a View Before the Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, razor, convention-over-configur

I created a Razor View by creating a new folder in my Solution under the Views folder, and then I right clicked that folder and selected "Add View".

Later, I went to my Controller folder and right clicked it, selecting "Add Controller". However, now I want to attach the view I created to my controller and it Visual Studio does not recognize that my view exists when I do:

```
return View("MyViewName");
```

How do I make Visual Studio recognize my already existing view? I would rather not resolve the issue by using Resharper to create my Razor view (since I've already created the view).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your view in correct (conventional) folder?

Comment: did you make sure to name the view folder the same as the controller name?

Comment: Ah, yes having the folder name and controller name match works. However, now I have to make a new view folder for every controller? Even if I am only interested in maybe one or two actions per controller?

Answer (score 3):

No need to write something, your folder must be named as controller. If you want other folder name, then type full path:

```
return View("~/Views/MyCustomFolder/MyViewName.cshtml");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is [convention over configuration](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration&ei=M19bUPqUB8rYqgHlmoGACA&usg=AFQjCNEanUn1HhJxMPMNNPZjHdKHtkDOaQ&sig2=7CvUqeYV-Uxrui9jufD7nQ) concept of ASP.NET MVC
Your controller action should be called the same as view:

```
public class MyBeautifulController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult MyActionIndex()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

thank your view should be called and located like this: `~/Views/MyBeautiful/MyActionIndex.cshtml`

Basically you dropping the last "Controller" in your controller class name.

This is COC (Convention Over Configuration). Now, if you want to call a view that is not called like your action, you will do the following in your action:

```
public class MyBeautifulController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult MyActionIndex()
  {
    return View("ViewCalledDifferently", new MyModel());
  }
}
```

and in this case, your view will be called and located like this:
`~/Views/MyBeautiful/ViewCalledDifferently.cshtml` and will accept MyModel as model type.

Hope this helps.